# Rank and Match Variables in Articulate Storyline / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, articulate-storyline, articulate

I hope anybody can help. I want to rank (13) scores (variables) that are determined through an assessment. The scores then need to be ranked (descending order) and then match to variables RankOne, RankTwo, etc.

```js
var player = GetPlayer();
```

Comment: Please show some **code**: example input (array?), desired output, and your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: ´here's the latest code:
var player = GetPlayer();
var Analytical_Score = player.GetVar("Analytical_Score");
var Collaborative_Score = player.GetVar("Collaborative_Score");
var Adaptable_Score = player.GetVar("Adaptable_Score");



var data = [Analytical_Score, Collaborative_Score, Adaptable_Score];


var count = 0;
var values = [] ;

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

count = count+1
}

var data1 = new Array();

// $.each( data, function( key, value ) {

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

data1[i] = data[i].value;

}

Comment: // these code are important for reading the score. need to call these variables after sorting is done
// var RankOne = data[0];
// var RankTwo = data[1];
// var RankThree = data[2];

document.write(data[i] + "<br >" ) ;

// for descending order
data1.reverse(data1.sort());
// for ascending order
data1.sort();
player.SetVar("OrderScore",data);

Comment: Here is the Storyline file: https: // we.tl/t-EypDuJCHXn

Answer (score 0):

Which part are you struggling with?

```js
const scores = [17, 98, 45, 41, 67, 12, 39, 90, 11, 25, 83, 77, 53];

scores.sort().reverse();

const rankOne = scores[0]; 
const rankTwo = scores[1]; 
const rankThree = scores[2];

console.log(rankOne, rankTwo, rankThree);
// 98 90 83
```

If you don't want to alter `scores` then copy it instead using `[...scores]` or `slice()` before sorting:

```js
const scoresDescending = scores.slice().sort().reverse();
```

Comment: This is a good start but it needs to work with Articulate Storyline. Are you familiar with this software?

Comment: @Euvouria No, I am not. Please edit your question, add your code, and explain how it needs to work with AS.

Comment: Do you have Articulate Storyline? The code needs to work within this software.

Comment: I have 13 Variables XX_score. Their scores are determined through an assessment that the user takes. Then, the scores need to be ranked and matched to the variables RankOne, RankTwo, etc.

Comment: How do I post the code? I use ``but it shows up as text.

Comment: @Euvouria I added a bit of code to your question as an example. Please add the rest and further explanation, and then delete any comments you have made which belong in the question.